React app FCM getToken() --> Failed to execute 'subscribe' on 'PushManager': Subscription failed - no active Service Worker
firebase-messaging-sw.js file is created successfully in the root directory.(public folder)
In this file configured background message setup's.
in my src directory I have firebase.js file.
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getMessaging, getToken } from "firebase/messaging";

const firebaseConfig = {firebase credentials};
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

export const messaging = getMessaging(app);
export const generateToken = async() => {
    try {
      console.log('Notification permission granted.');
      await requestPermission();
      await getFcmToken();
    }
    catch(e) {
      console.log("error",e)
    }
}

const requestPermission = async() => {
  console.log('Requesting permission...');
  await Notification.requestPermission().then((permission) => {
    if (permission === 'granted') {
      console.log('Notification permission granted.');
    }
  });
}

const getFcmToken = async () => {
  console.log("called");
  const fcmToken = await getToken(messaging, { vapidKey: vapid' })
  console.log('token', fcmToken);
}

when I call the getToken() function it produces error,
"Failed to execute 'subscribe' on 'PushManager': Subscription failed - no active Service Worker"
getToken() is automatically register my service worker and activated.
Above error happen only during the first time, second time successfully got FCM token.
firebase-messaging-sw.js
firebase.initializeApp({
  apiKey: 'api-key',
  authDomain: 'project-id.firebaseapp.com',
  databaseURL: 'https://project-id.firebaseio.com',
  projectId: 'project-id',
  storageBucket: 'project-id.appspot.com',
  messagingSenderId: 'sender-id',
  appId: 'app-id',
  measurementId: 'G-measurement-id',
});

// Retrieve an instance of Firebase Messaging so that it can handle background
// messages.
const messaging = firebase.messaging();
messaging.onBackgroundMessage((payload) => {
  console.log(
    '[firebase-messaging-sw.js] Received background message ',
    payload
  );
  // Customize notification here
  const notificationTitle = 'Background Message Title';
  const notificationOptions = {
    body: 'Background Message body.',
    icon: '/firebase-logo.png'
  };

  self.registration.showNotification(notificationTitle, notificationOptions);
});

How i can resolve the error?
